# Spring Boot 1.5.2 Hibernate - Cannot save non-ASCII character (µ) to postgresql properly?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a java web application using Spring Boot 1.52 version and in application.properties file, I have this configuration to connect to postgresql.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_utf8
```

I have a model class which represents a table by Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "coverage")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Coverage implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "metadata")
    @Lob
    private String metadata;

}
```

And this service class to save the Coverage object to database.

```
@Transactional
public interface CoverageRepository extends CrudRepository<Coverage, String> {

}
```

And I use this repository service to save the **Coverage** object to database:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CoverageRepositoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CoverageRepository coverageRepository;

    public void save(Coverage coverage) {
       coverageRepository.save(coverage);
    }

}
```

Everything works great, except when the metadata has the non-ascii character **µ**. I checked in postgresql database, it will be saved like this **\265** and in the Spring Boot web application, it will display as �  character.

```
Postgresql:

select encode(data, 'escape') from coverage c, pg_largeobject lo
where c.metadata::int=lo.loid
```

The table in postgresql is set to UTF-8:

```
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

test_utf8=# SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Does anybody know, what can be wrong here from Spring Boot / Hibernate to properly save this non-ascii character to postgresql/

**Update 1**

If I remove the from **@Lob** and change to

```
@Column(name = "metadata", columnDefinition = "text")
private String metadata;
```

Then it can store the **µ** character fine in postgresql

So there must be a problem with this **@Lob** from Hibernate to Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the problem. It was due to the Postgresql JDBC version in pom.xml file of my java web application

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

There was a historical reason for this JDBC problem long time ago from Postgresql which developers of Hibernate found out: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6127

Then, I just need to update pom.xml to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and then it can save the non-unicode character properly to database.